# It's cloudy vs It's black cloudy

Tags: grammar

It seems to be rain soon and the sky was cloudy.

> "It's cloudy."
>
> "It's black cloudy."

How do we different the cloudy as the images?

One is sunny with cloud and another is cloudy and about to rain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Black cloudy" is not an idiomatic term in Britain. "The sky's black", "there is heavy cloud", are the sorts of terms used. The adjective "cloudy" is one that is rarely moderated, except with such as "it's very cloudy", "it's a little bit cloudy" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weather forecasters use terms like:

> ***light clouds*** => White patches of clouds
>
> ***dark clouds*** => Gray or black clouds
>
> ***heavy clouds*** => Clouds that look like they could drop rain at any time
>
> ***gray skies*** => When you can't see the sun because of a layer of gray cloud
>
> ***overcast*** => Same as gray skies. You can't see the sun.
>
> ***clear skies / blue skies*** => A blue sky during the day.
>
> ***mostly sunny*** => The sky is mostly blue with a few clouds.
>
> ***partly sunny*** => The sky is blue but there are a number of clouds.
>
> ***partly cloudy*** => The sky has a considerable number of clouds.
>
> ***mostly cloudy*** => The sky is mostly filled with clouds.

Most native speakers would describe the sky as one of the following:

> ***It's sunny.***
>
> ***It's a little cloudy.***
>
> ***It's cloudy.***
>
> ***It's very cloudy.***
>
> ***It's gray/dark/black.***

And when people describe the weather as ***drizzly*** or ***rainy***, that obviously means the clouds are very dark.